# Python Machine Learning: class labels in a cycle to reflect correlations between classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, classification, multilabel-classification

I have a time series that I want to predict (using Neural Network, but is not important) with machine learning in python.

On top of using the info at previous values ($t-1$, $t-2$, ...etc) I want to use another variable: the *hour of the day*.

**Stupid Method**

One way would be to map:

> $00:00 \rightarrow 0 $
>
> $01:00 \rightarrow 1$

....
and so on. So I woul have $24$ classes ${0,1,2,..., 23}$. However there is a problem: $23$ and $0$ are close, but at the same time this is not reflected here.

**second method: one hot encoding?**

Another way would be to create vectors with $24$ entries where all the elements are zero, apart from the class that we are looking at. This is equivalent to creating dummy variables. For instance:

> $00:00 \rightarrow [1,0,0,0,....,0]$
>
> $01:00 \rightarrow [0,1,0,0,...,0]$

...and so on. However there is a problem: this doesn not reflect correlation at all!

**Other Method**

I was thinking of using some cyclic structure, for instance $sin$, $cos$ or maybe polar coordinates?

I haven't found the solution yet, but this is my progress:

1. Map the class labels of the stupid method to $[0,1]$, by normalizing them
2. Scale them to be in the range from $0$ to $2\pi$.
3. Use $cos$ or $sin$ on them.

This method doesn't quite work, but I can see some light.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I sort of found a solution. From the class labels `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` we construct the following

```
array([[ 0, 15, 24, 33, 42, 51],
       [ 1, 10, 25, 34, 43, 52],
       [ 2, 11, 20, 35, 44, 53],
       [ 3, 12, 21, 30, 45, 54],
       [ 4, 13, 22, 31, 40, 55],
       [ 5, 14, 23, 32, 41, 50]])
```

This is created by using the class labels as the first column. Then the second column starts from 10 and goes to 15 but it is shifted so that the "gap" is between the first and the second label, instead of the last and the first. You repeat this.

Then you assign

```
0 --> [ 0, 15, 24, 33, 42, 51]
1 --> [ 1, 10, 25, 34, 43, 52]
```

and so on..
Then taking the norm fo the difference of any two "adjacent" vector-classes is the same. Thus we don't have any gap.

I think might sort of work, but I am not sure whether I could feed this into a feature

Comment: actually, this doesn't work as if we dot product this matrix with a  weight vector (or matrix), resulting entries have lost their "closeness